# actions not using default working directory

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repository with some subdirectories. One of the subdirectory is called `gradle-specific` which is the gradle project. I want to run `./gradlew clean build` using github actions. My `yaml` file looks as follows:

```yaml
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: ./gradle-specific
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 16
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '16'
        distribution: 'temurin'
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
      with:
        arguments: clean build
```

but error logs indicate that the build is happening in the root folder itself:

```
Error: Error: Cannot locate a Gradle wrapper properties file at '/home/runner/work/service-commons/service-commons/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'. Specify 'gradle-version' or 'gradle-executable' for projects without Gradle wrapper configured.
```

where `service-commons` is my repository name

I tried specifying the working directory without relative path, with relative path, specifying globally. I am following https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun to configure the same

Comment: Have you tried the `gradle-executable` option for `gradle-build-action` action?

Comment: I have, it gives error `Task 'clean' not found in root project 'service-commons'`. the only way I was successfully able to run gradle clean build was discarding `gradle-build-action` completely and directly execute `./gradlew clean build` along with working directory as `gradle-specific`